# Is it legal to bet on other people without their consent?

Tags: canada, gambling

Is it legal for people of legal gambling age to bet on other people without them consenting to be bet on. For example, can they bet on what grade a certain individual will get on an exam, or on what clothes that person will wear, etc.?

Comment: How would you find out their grade without their consent? Are grades not private information in the Canadian educational system?

Comment: Also keep in mind that even if legal under the law, it might be forbidden by the rules of your school (possibly as a type of harassment).

Comment: In principle you can bet on anything, but there may be issues with data protection or even harassment (and betting on e.g. someone's murder may see authorities inventing ingenious ways to prosecute you). You should probably state which Canadian state you're in, as precise laws vary.

Comment: A couple of clarifications regarding this: I gave grades as an example to keep it simple but it will likely be something more publically available such as clothing that is worn or what job this person will have. This is in Quebec

Comment: @StuartF Canada has provinces, not states.

Comment: A slightly more general question might better capture the sense of the law: "Is it legal in Canada (or in particular Canadian provinces), to gamble in ways not specifically authorized by law?" I suspect that the answer is "no".

Comment: I thought you need to have a license to operate any betting system in Canada...

Comment: @ohwilleke and Trish: [Section 204(1)(b) of the Criminal Code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/arm64-windows-abi-conventions?view=msvc-170) specifically exempts "a private bet between individuals not engaged in any way in the business of betting".  No license required.  I assumed that was what OP had in mind.

Comment: There is a very old limit against insuring someone else's life. You have to have an insurable interest in their life, such as being a family member or business partner. The reason to require this is that otherwise this would encourage murder. You might say more about what kinds of events or characteristics you might bet on.